# Is a Minhag for a Baal Teshuva considered a Neder?

Tags: tefilla, nusach-ashkenaz, baal-teshuva, minhag

A Baal Teshuva that comes from an Ashkenazi family, became observant thru a Chabad house, with no understanding of different Nusachim and no intention to become a Lubavitcher, only to become more observant. He acquired Chabad Tefillin and keeps davening Nusach HaAri.

One day he listens to [a Shiur](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=55647) and realizes the importance of following the father's traditions (his father davens 3 times a day) and wants to switch back to Ashkenazi Nosach and eventually Ashkenazi Teffilin.

Does performing a certain Minhag becomes a Neder? For how long?
Can he switch [back] from Nosach Ari to Ashkenazi both in Nosach and Teffilin? And how to cancel a Neder if anything?

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2018/07/31/minhagim-for-baal-teshuva/ Happy to see you got your answer

Comment: Is this a dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90248/9682? What’s the policy here - should it be reopened to be closed again as a dupe? Does a mod open and shut it? @DoubleAA

Comment: @donielf consider  https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4674/759

Comment: @Yaakov Chabad holds that you cannot change your nusach from HaAri to Ashkenaz. But I am unsure as to whether you would need to hold by Chabad on that ruling. Someone expressed to me an interesting idea, taken from a gemara about the sale of slaves, that you can hold by your anticipated future shitah when negotiating a shayle about the transition. Ideally, ask a rav [which rav you should ask]

Comment: @SAH can you please give more information on where the idea about the sale of slaves is in gemara?

Comment: @Yaakov I wish, but I don't remember. The person who told me wasn't sure this gemara could be used for a practical ruling in this way and told me to ask a rav. I then asked another rabbi who said this justification was "interesting" but ruled against my particular scenario for a different reason